# gvChart (Google Chart) jquery plugin. How to call functions on events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-visualization

I'm using [this](http://www.ivellios.toron.pl/technikalia/2010/06/22/gvchart-plugin-jquery-with-google-charts/) plugin ([Github](https://github.com/ivellios/gvChart)), which is using Google Charts (to draw a PieChart). I want to use select event and getSelection() method from Google's api. For example, alert the element's id when the user clicks it. How to make it happen?

[Google's documentation on the plugin.](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, guys) I don't need the plugin anymore. It's much easier to use Google's code instead of using that jQuery plugin.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```